# Instead of just using free() and having the pointer pointing some new block, how to really empty the previously-pointed-at memory block?

Tags: c

I am trying to free dynamically allocated memory using free(), but I found that what it does is to have the argument pointer point to some new location, and leaving the previously-pointed-at location as it was, the memory is not cleared. And if I use malloc again, the pointer may point to this messy block, and it's already filled with garbage, which is really annoying..

I'm kinda new to C and I think delete[] in c++ doesn't have this problem. Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: In C there are no guarantees about a block of memory that you receive.  You can always do a memset to 0 if you need that.

Comment: Use calloc() instead of malloc().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is having newly allocated memory filled with garbage "really annoying"?  If you allocate memory, presumably it's because you're going to use it for something -- which means you have to store some meaningful value into it *before* attempting to read it.  In most cases, in well-written code, there's no reason to *care* what's in newly allocated memory.

If you happen to have a requirement for a newly allocated block of memory you can call `memset` after calling `malloc`, or you can use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  But consider carefully whether there's any real advantage in doing so.  If you're actually going to *use* those all-bits-zero values (i.e., if all-bits-zero happens to be the "meaningful value" I mentioned above), go ahead and clear the block.  (But keep in mind that the language doesn't guarantee that either a null pointer or a floating-point 0.0 is represented as all-bits-zero, though it is in most implementations they are.)

And `free()` doesn't "have the argument pointer point to some new location".  `free(ptr)` causes the memory pointed to by `ptr` to be made available for future allocation.  It doesn't change the contents of the pointer object `ptr` itself (though the address stored in `ptr` does become invalid).

Answer (score 6):

By `free` the memory is just released from use. It is released from being allocated to you. it is not explicitly cleared. Some old contents might be present at those memory locations. 
To avoid this, there are two solutions.

### Solution 1:

You will need to do a `memset` after allocating memory using `malloc`.

**Code Example:**

```
unsigned int len = 20; // len is the length of boo
char* bar = 0;
bar= (char *)malloc(len);

memset(bar, 0, len);
```

### Solution 2:

Or use, `calloc()` which initiliazes memory to `0` by default.

**Code Example:**

```
  int *pData = 0;
  int i = 10;
  pData = (int*) calloc (i,sizeof(int));
```

---

### I think `delete[]` in c++ doesn't have this problem.

**No**
It behaves exactly this same way. Unless you explicitly set the pointer to `0` the `delete`'d pointer will not be pointing to `0`. So do always set the pointer to `0` after you delete it.

---

### When should you use `malloc` over `calloc` or vice versa?

Since `calloc` sets the allocated memory to `0` this may take a little time, so you may probably want to use `malloc()` if that performance is an issue.(Ofcourse One most profile their usage to see if this really is a problem)

If initializing the memory is more important, use `calloc()` as it does that explicitly for you.

Also, some OS like Linux have an **Lazy Allocation memory model** wherein the returned memory address is a virtual address and the actual allocation only happens at run-time. The OS assumes that it will be able to provide this allocation at Run-Time.

The memory allocated by `malloc` is not backed by real memory until the program actually touches it.

While, since `calloc` initializes the memory to `0` you can be assured that the OS has already backed the allocation with actual RAM (or swap).

---

### How about `realloc`?

Yes, similar behavior to `malloc`.
Excerpt From the **[documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/)**:

```
void * realloc ( void * ptr, size_t size );
```

**Reallocate memory block**

The size of the memory block pointed to by the ptr parameter is changed to the size bytes, expanding or reducing the amount of memory available in the block.

The function may move the memory block to a new location, in which case the new location is returned. **The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the new and old sizes, even if the block is moved.If the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is indeterminate.**

In case that ptr is NULL, the function behaves exactly as malloc, assigning a new block of size bytes and returning a pointer to the beginning of it.

In case that the size is 0, the memory previously allocated in ptr is deallocated as if a call to free was made, and a NULL pointer is returned.

Comment: Thank you, also I want to know if calloc is so clean why would anyone want to use malloc? also, does realloc behave the same as malloc?

Comment: Why would you want to spend time filling memory with zero when you're about to fill it with something meaningful as the next step of your program? (Or when you're storing a string in the memory, and everything past the null terminator will be ignored.)

Comment: @Rachel: A little delayed but Updated the answer to answer your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calloc( )` instead of `malloc( )` to clear the allocated memory to zero.