# Was I just lucky that malloc returned a zero-filled buffer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc

I tried running the code below:

```
int main(){
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
ptr[5] = 'W';
ptr[0] = 'H';
std::cout<<ptr<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I use GCC 4.3.4 and I get "H" as output. The book *C Programming Language* by Kernighan & Ritchie says malloc() returns uninitialized space, in which case the output should have been some undefined value. Is my output just a result of a coincidence of ptr[1] being '\0'?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421502/instead-of-just-using-free-and-having-the-pointer-pointing-some-new-block-how/7421564#7421564) might be a good read for you.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's just a coincidence. Don't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be coincidence, or it may be an feature of your particular system's memory allocator, it is certainly not a language or library requirement to initialise dynamically allocated memory.

Don't confuse *non-deterministic* with *random*, even if the memory is uninitialised, the chances of that byte being zero are probably far greater than 1/256 due to typical memory usage patterns.  For example open up a memory window in your debugger on `ptr`  and scroll through the adjacent memory in either direction, you are likely to to see zero rather a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's platform (and compile mode) dependent, eg in debug compile might get filled with some pattern, like 0x55 0xaa 0x55, in production you might get 0x00-s, or any memory garbage.
So yes, you might declare it as a conincidence.
You might easily got a bus error (or invalid memory access), as your string is not always  terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But be careful in terminology, ptr[1] is int 0, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Null termination is the correct word I guess.